# C: Change char in string

Tags: c, arrays, char, digit

While this is a basic question, the exact situation is different from average.  I have char board[] = {"13572"} that represents a board (the index of the array is the row of the board and the int (represented as a char) is the number of elements in that row.  If the user inputs "3 3" that means they want to change the number of elements at index 2 to be 2 (Or as the user sees it change the number of elements in row 3 to 2, also the user believes the index is from 1-4 for Y and 1-7 for X), changing board to {"13272"}.  I am having an issue where input can change the value in the selected row to be '/' or '0' instead of the desired value. Any advice is appreciated, the relevant functions are below:

Also, board is a global variable.
Changes chars in an array to ints(single digits):

```
int bd2int (char board[], int index){
    char buff[2] = {board[index],'\0'};
    return atoi(buff);
}
```

changes the board based on move (char move[3] in format "X Y"): I believe the issue is here, when printing the board as a string if index 2 was changed the board will only print to index 1, indicating that a '\0' was inserted at index 2.

```
int update(char move[]){
   int x;
   int y;
   x = bd2int(move,0);
   y = bd2int(move,2);
   x--;
   board[y-1] = (char)x;
   totalElements=    bd2int(board,0)+bd2int(board,1)+bd2int(board,2)+bd2int(board,3);
   return 1;
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, but if you have `char board[] = "13572";` and you want to change the `5` to `2`, then `board[2] = '2';` (note the quotes for **character value** `'2' (decimal 50)` not decimal `2`.

Comment: I'm not sure it is directly relevant, but note that `"X Y"` requires a `char move[4];` (or larger) to store the trailing null byte too.  Please create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) which reproduces the problem and does not require user input.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin the issue I am having is that the desired index will occasionally change to '\0' instead of what the user inputs.  Due to the rules for a move (that I did not mention) the x value from the user needs to be decremented by 1 before replacing the current value on the board, I believe the way I handle this is causing '\0' to appear instead of the correct result.

Comment: Why are you storing the board positions as char and not an array of short integers?  Do you need those 8 bits?

Comment: @Schwern I am not concerned about performance and the functions shown are on a server that send the char array board to clients on different machines and they interpret the board for display.  I believe that chars are easier to use for the inter-process communication than shorts.

Comment: @CSjunkie If your index is changing to `'\0'`, then the user is likely doing something (like just hitting the `[Enter]` key) resulting in bad input. We need a MCVE as Johathan requested.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I am working on a MCVE, but I am guaranteed that the user will not enter an invalid move as the request for a move will reject invalid moves and request a new one before sending it to these functions.  The only moves allowed are 0<Y<5 and 0<X<board[Y] in the format X Y

Comment: @JonathanLeffler as it stands now, making any move results in the value at index Y-1 being changed to '\0'

Comment: The line `board[y-1] = (char)x;` seems problematic, since you expect `x` to have a value of, say, 2 (as an integer), but as a character, that represents the `STX` (start of text) character, not the character `'2'`. You may want to consider using `sprint()` to get it back into the proper character value.

Comment: @akivag29 do you mean `sprintf()`? I believe that requires the use of pointers if I'm not mistaken,  I would like to be able to avoid using pointers but I agree that the issue seems to reside on that line.

Comment: @CSjunkie You are using arrays, which I believe are essentially equivalent to pointers with the syntactic sugar of bracketed subscripting (a detailed explanation [here](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/ch2x.htm)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the assistance, the issue was line `board[y-1] = (char)x;` I found a more accurate way to convert int x to char x that fixed the issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114741/how-to-convert-int-to-char-c